# run two services in a docker image

Tags: docker

How to run two services in a docker image?

I have `CMD ["/datomic/run.sh"]` but I also want 
`CMD ["bin/console -p 8080 dev datomic:free://localhost:4334/"]` as well to run after the first one started. Both commands takes up shell.
How to do this?

Comment: Typically speaking, the most "docker-ish" way to deploy your app asks you to not to run multiple services in one container. Could you tell me what's the end goal that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: but it is a database - so console is used to query the same DB.

Comment: I'm not familiar with datomic but I assume that `localhost:4334/` is the link to your db. You can use another container to do it with a modified link.

Comment: Yes - I can. but my question is how to make it work on the same ...

Comment: Docker enforces some design-pattern to deploy your application and having more than one service in one container is an anti-pattern that nobody would suggest. If you do not want a second contianer in your deployment cycle, you can create ephemeral containers using `--rm` containers that run a command and get terminated. If you still insist that you need one and ONLY ONE container, write an entrypoint script that start one of your services and demonizes it to put it in background and then start your other service. Good luck!

Comment: `"/datomic/run.sh` If this is just a bash script put it inot `entrypoint` run it and after this you run `"bin/console -p 8080 dev datomic:free://localhost:4334/". I think you do not need multip service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use Supervisord to Run multiple services in a container.

Have a look to this document from docker docs !!
(https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)